# Torch OpenCV integration

Tags: opencv, torch

I want to install opencv package in torch. I have already installed opencv and it is working fine. After using `luarocks install cv` for installing cv package in torch I am getting following error.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (FIND_PACKAGE):
Could not find a configuration file for package "OpenCV" that exactly
matches requested version "3.1".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

/home/user/opencv-3.1.0/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake, version: unknown
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake, version: 3.3.0



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/luarocks_cv-scm-1-5467/torch-
opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at installation guide from the [GitHub page](https://github.com/VisionLabs/torch-opencv/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

`torch-opencv` requires `opencv-3.1.0` and is not (yet) compatible with `opencv-3.3.0`.

Therefore, you need to install `opencv-3.1.0`

```
git clone https://github.com/daveselinger/opencv
cd opencv
git checkout 3.1.0-with-cuda8

mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
    -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
make
sudo make install
luarocks install cv
```

if your **cuda version** is not 8, you should change it.